# How to get ordered this sql query

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

#### comments table

[comments table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwa3J.png)

#### stars table

[stars table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlSL3.png)

i write this query: (for ordering sites by most stars_sum)

```php
$comments->join('stars', 'comments.star_id', '=', 'stars.id');
$comments->selectRaw('comments.site_id as site_id, comments.id as comment_id, stars.key1 + stars.key2 + stars.key3 + stars.key4 + stars.key5 as stars_sum');
$comments->groupByRaw('site_id, comment_id DESC');
```

```sql
select comments.site_id as site_id, comments.id as comment_id, stars.key1 + stars.key2 + stars.key3 + stars.key4 + stars.key5 as stars_sum from `comments` inner join `stars` on `comments`.`star_id` = `stars`.`id` where `comments`.`deleted_at` is null group by site_id, comment_id DESC
```

#### query result

[stars table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9kLb.png)

but i want result like this:

| site_id | stars_sum |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ... |
| 2 | ... |
| 3 | ... |

Comment: @brombeer because this stars for 5 different thing

Comment: You are grouping by `site_id` and `comment_id` if you want the sum all starts for each site for all comments you'd probably need something like `SUM(stars.key1)+SUM(starts.key2)...` and not have the `comment_id` in the select at all

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for

```
Comment::selectRaw('comments.site_id as site_id, SUM(stars.key1) + SUM(stars.key2) + SUM(stars.key3) + SUM(stars.key4) + SUM(stars.key5) as stars_sum');
    ->join('stars', 'comments.star_id', '=', 'stars.id')
    ->groupBy('site_id')
    ->orderByDesc('stars_sum');
```

Comment: please add an explanation how this code solve the question